# Find accounts that vote for an inflation destination

Tags: inflation

Is it possible to view the set of accounts that vote for any given inflation destination?

For example, this is [a popular inflation destination](https://stellar.expert/explorer/account/GCCD6AJOYZCUAQLX32ZJF2MKFFAUJ53PVCFQI3RHWKL3V47QYE2BNAUT). How can I fetch a list of accounts that have voted for this destination?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you did not want to rely on a 3rd party to gather this data you could run a stellar node and query the postgres database directly.

https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/d6fc518b80afa9731557120f831df06b592db1b0/src/ledger/AccountFrame.cpp#L232

I have used the stellar-core code above to give an idea of the query you would need to run.

```
db.getPreparedStatement("SELECT accountid, balance, inflationdest "
                        "FROM accounts WHERE inflationdest = :inflationdest");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [fed.netwok](https://fed.network)'s `inflation` public API endpoint to get the list of accounts that has voted for an inflation destination. In your case the URL would be:

https://fed.network/inflation/GCCD6AJOYZCUAQLX32ZJF2MKFFAUJ53PVCFQI3RHWKL3V47QYE2BNAUT